# Why this strange definition for PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED

Tags: c

In `pthread.h`, one could find the following definition:

```
/* Detach state.  */
enum
{
  PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE,
#define PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE
  PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED
#define PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED
};
```

Why this definition mixing enum and defines? How to interpret it? Besides, the `#define` is defining something to the same.

Comment: Where did you get this file? On which environment? Are you sure it was not modified in any way ('replace all' seems like a probable cause)?

Comment: It's funny how somebody else spotted the same thing, and asked about it on a Linux message board in Russian ([link (Russian)](http://www.linux.org.ru/forum/development/1914780)).

Comment: @asaf: is just my regular /usr/include/pthread.h on RHEL 6.4

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: (OT) I really love on that board the "ИМХО" for IMHO: that is Rusglish :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE` and `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED` need to be used in `#ifdef` statements ([here is an example of source code where it is used in this way](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/CHM/PDL-2.006/Basic/Core/pdlmagic.h)). The authors needed to define their names to their values, otherwise the preprocessor would not let you use the corresponding `enum` value.

Comment: Could you please elaborate it, or give some example? I don't understand 1) Does the enum got an error: double definition if the macro expanded? `enum
{
  PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE,
  PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE,
  PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED,
  PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED
};`  2) Your reference in the link is just `undef  PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE`, it's not very evidential.